# Error in an example from book - "Unexpected token {"

Tags: javascript

I was reading a book on JavaScript (recently started to learn). While running one of the examples from a book, I get an error. I'm using Chromium browser on Ubuntu, 14.0.835.202.

Since I'm a newbie, I can't understand why there is an error. Thanks in advance.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, fn)
{
    this.prototype[name] = fn;
    return this;
};


var Person
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};


Person.
    method ("getName", function
    { // error here - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"
        return this.name;
    }).
    method ("getAge", function
    {
        return this.age;
    });


var alice = new Person ("Alice", 93);
var bill = new Person ("Bill", 30);

Person.
    method ("getGreeting", function
    {
        return "Hi" + this.getName() + "!";
    });

alert (alice.getGreeting());
```

EDIT:

The solution gave me another question that I wanted to ask. For object declaration:

```
var Object = function (...) // line 1
{
    // code here
};
```

if the number of variables is so big that I don't want to list them in line 1, what can I do?

Comment: Don't put your braces on a new line. [It actually matters](http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/).

Comment: I feel somebody should say this. Whenever you define a function, even if anonymous or without any expected parameters, you still need to put the paranthesises behind `function` or the name of the function.

Comment: What book are you reading? Is this exactly what's in the book? If so... stop reading that book.

Comment: There are many things wrong here. Check out the link from vcsjones and the answer from Sirko

Comment: now it complains that "age is not defined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `=` (and very likely a `function` as well) here:

```
var Person = function( name, age ){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};
```

Likewise later on your are missing some parenthesis in your function definitions, e.g.:

```
method ("getName", function()
    {
        return this.name;
    }).
```

Comment: Should actually still be wrong. Should be `name : name, age : age`, no?

Comment: @Derija93 Right, but with respect to the rest of the code, it should probably a function definition.

Comment: @Sirko Now it makes sense. ;)

Comment: why is it showing "age is not defined" after adding these brackets?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev Another oversight by me: I forgot to add the function parameters in the contructor definition for `Person`.

Comment: so if the object is big enough so that i'll be too lazy to list all variables in function (...) what should i do to avoid it?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev At some point you have to list them. Either by using the constructor or something like `alice['bday'] = 'her birthday';`

Comment: can you show the example on "alice['bday'] = 'her birthday';" in an edit?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30132/discussion-between-sirko-and-kudayar-pirimbaev)

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
function
    {
```

But

```
function ()
    {
```

The sintax in which you are declaring your functions is wrong. The `()` (or `(par1, par2, parEtc)`) after the `function` keyword are mandatory.

Also, the declaration of `var Person` is invalid. The sintax is `var varName = expression`. You are missing the `=`. Also, your `expression` is likely to be a `function` with the parameters `name` and `age`.

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
};
```

Changing that, your code works. [**See demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rZsq/).